# Windows Phone - Navigation to Other Pages

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone

Let us say that I have a windows phone application with 5 pages:

1. Log-in
2. Main Menu (after successful log-in)
3. Make Payment (accessed from Main Menu)
4. Enter Credit Card Details (accessed from Main Menu)
5. View Previous Payments (accessed from Main Menu)

Can the user navigate to any page he likes using some sort of URL in a windows phone app?  For instance, in websites, the user can navigate to any page by typing the URL in the address bar.  Then it is up to the programmer to check the session to see if the user is authorized to view the page.

Does this scenario apply to a Windows Phone app?  Or is the user restricted to follow the flow of the program as dictated by the developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user cannot navigate freely inside a Windows Phone App, it must follow the path that is defined by the developer. You have to define the interactions. The only problem that i can find is with the backward navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That's what I wanted to hear :)  Thanks again :)